# How to format mailgun api in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, api, email, mailgun

In my code I have correctly installed mailgun using cocoapods. My code compiles but it is not sending an email to the email address in the to:. I do not see an email. I am not listing the apiKey for security purposes but I am using the 30 character private string called the private api. From the tutorial on mailgun sites it appears that I did it correctly but it is not working.

```
import UIKit
import Mailgun_In_Swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sam()
    }

    let mailgun = MailgunAPI(apiKey: "", clientDomain: "upsidefor@yahoo.com")

    func sam() {
        mailgun.sendEmail(to: "upsidefor@yahoo.com", from: "maxmadill@Yahoo.com>", subject: "This is a test", bodyHTML: "<b>test<b>") { mailgunResult in
            if mailgunResult.success{
                print("Email was sent")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: contact to mailgun's support.this is not about the code.

Comment: Try to set Allow Arbitrary Loads in App Transport security settings to YES